Plotting discrete/categorical rasters with custom colors slows down R/terra
I've got a simple but frustrating problem. Here is an example raster (nothing huge, about 2 Mb):
[file link]
library(terra)
continuous <- rast("example.tif")

# Figure 1
plot(continuous)

# Figure 2
discrete <- continuous > 0.1
plot(discrete)

# Figure 3
plot(discrete, col=c("blue","red"))


Drawing figure 1 is no problem, and drawing figure 2 is very quick.
But for some reason, drawing figure 3 slows down R something dreadful. It takes almost ten seconds. Tabbing to it in the figure viewer is also slow. What's going on, and is there a way to fix it?

What GUI are you using? RStudio? VS Code? From a plain old text-based R console I don't see anything like that with these plots, but GUI graphics devices may wrap R's graphics such that things can slow done (eg RStudio keeping entire plot history...). Try it from a console? (although I just fired up RStudio and it seems fine there for me too...)

I'm using RStudio, but even when I try it from the regular RGUI, plot 3 is still slower. Not quite as slow, but there's a dramatic difference between 2 and 3.

Might be some version specific problem... Can you add your operating system and  version numbers of R and the terra package to your question - and upgrade first if they're not the latest.

What happens if you set the default colours with options(terra.pal=c("blue","red")) and then plot(discrete) to get the same red-blue raster but with the same first plot command that isn't slow? Am really throwing ideas around at this point...

Or try to add coltab to the raster itself prior to plotting, see https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/colors.html.

@Gregorz Sapijaszko Yep, setting a coltab does fix the slowness problem, thanks!

This has been fixed in the development version of "terra". I now get:
library(terra)
#terra 1.8.2
r <- rast("example.tif")
d <- r > 0.1
system.time(plot(r))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.31    0.08    0.41 
system.time(plot(d))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.10    0.07    0.16 
system.time(plot(d, col=c("blue","red")))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.06    0.10    0.14

A work-around with the current CRAN version is to use the hex-codes instead of color names:
system.time(plot(d, col=c("#0000FF", "#FF0000")))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.12    0.01    0.14 

On windows and mac, you can install the development version of "terra" with
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')

And see https://github.com/rspatial/terra for instructions for other platforms.

Thanks a lot Robert! Switching to hex codes worked like a charm.
